# UIPageControl - Lonely indicator is visible, although hidesForSinglePage is true

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

Although I've set hidesForSinglePage to true, the lonely indicator is still visible. But not where the indicators normally are, but in the upper left corner (?!) of the page control. It's like it trying to hide by stepping aside, but fails by taking a few steps too little. I've been playing with all kinds of attributes, but none has even tweaked this strange behavior.

Does anyone have any clever clues?

Thanks,
Johannes

Answer (score 2):

I discovered when this bug came to life, and thus come up with a solution. I had set the number of pages of my page control to 1 in Interface Builder. When I changed this to a greater number, and then let my code set it back to 1 when the NIB had been loaded, the bug disappeared.

Very strange indeed...

Comment: That is interesting. You should file a bug report with Apple. http://bugreport.apple.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with new XCode 5 and iOS7. I didn't set up the UIPageControl via IB or Storyboard but within code. The problem occured because I had set `somePageControl.hidden = FALSE;` after I set the `pageCount = 1`. When I set `hidden = TRUE` before setting pageCount the single indicator disappears.